# vdx-6354 black screen after download finished

Tags: windows-ce

I worked step by step through installing OS image using static IP over vdx-6354. After Download finished a black screen remains for ever and nothing happens. I disable some extra check boxes like KILT and some other people and it official site said but not working at all! I also put a pic right after download finished, it showed transport is waiting, why? and what is stand for?

[image]
And one more thing does serial cable play the most important role in downloading OS image using Ethernet cable? Why if i unplug it? I did not find any difference.

**Additional :
I also get these texts using debug serial cable:**

```
PB Debugger The Kernel Debugger is waiting to connect with target.
PB Debugger The Kernel Debugger has been disconnected successfully.
PB Debugger The Kernel Debugger is waiting to connect with target.

      0 PID:0 TID:0 CEPC Firmware Init
      0 PID:0 TID:0 RTC - Status Reg B - 0x02
      0 PID:0 TID:0 g_dwCPUFeatures = 00000111
      0 PID:0 TID:0 Looking for rom chain
      0 PID:0 TID:0 Rom chain NOT found
      0 PID:0 TID:0 Firmware Init Done.
      0 PID:0 TID:0 Booting Windows CE version 6.00 for (x86)
      0 PID:0 TID:0 

Old or invalid version stamp in kernel structures - starting clean!

      0 PID:0 TID:0 Configuring: Primary pages: 55362, Secondary pages: 0, Filesystem pages = 27681
      0 PID:0 TID:0 
Booting kernel with clean memory configuration:

      0 PID:0 TID:0 Memory Sections:
      0 PID:0 TID:0 [0] : start: 826a2000, extension: 0001c000, length: 0d842000
      0 PID:0 TID:0 X86Init done, OEMAddressTable = 80226d20, RAM mapped = 10000000.
     11 PID:400002 TID:410002 Exception 'Access Violation' (14): Thread-

Id=00410002(pth=8feff024), Proc-Id=00400002(pprc=82617800) 'NK.EXE', VM-active=00400002(pprc=82617800) 'NK.EXE'

     11 PID:400002 TID:410002 PC=00000000(???+0x00000000) RA=c00429f5(hd.dll+0x000029f5) SP=d001fb10, BVA=00000000
     12 PID:400002 TID:410002 Eax=d001fb9c Ebx=826192e0 Ecx=d001fb9c Edx=d001fb9c
     12 PID:400002 TID:410002 Esi=00000000 Edi=00000001 Ebp=d001fb58 Esp=d001fb10 Eip=00000000
     12 PID:400002 TID:410002 CS=0019 DS=0040 ES=0040 SS=0021 FS=0060 GS=0000
     12 PID:400002 TID:410002 URtlDispatchException: returning failure. Flags=0
     12 PID:400002 TID:410002 

Unhandled exception c0000005:

     12 PID:400002 TID:410002 Terminating thread 8feff024
     13 PID:400002 TID:410002 Secondary thread in proc 00400002 faulted, Exception code = c0000005, Exception Address = 00000000!
     13 PID:400002 TID:410002 Terminating Thread 00410002
```